# Throw IP into the same server

Tags: php

I am looking for a function in php that allows throwing IP into the same server.

This is how I should throw their ip into the page, so I will hear what function devices that can locate the people's ip?

Comment: What is "throwing" an IP? It's really unclear what you are asking. If English isn't your first language, I understand, but please elaborate what you are trying to accomplish. If you're looking for a way to obtain the IP address, just use the variable `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

Comment: This post really isn't very clear, could you try to elaborate more on what you're trying to do and use better terminology.

Comment: @DaveChen You're hilarious, dude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for the remote client address?

```
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Comment: I have no idea how this answer relates to the question, as originally phrase...